# adding members to a telegram channel by their ID

Tags: telegram

I have a channel in telegram, and i want to add my customers to it.
I only have their Telegram IDs. 
How can i do this?
Is there any way to do so?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Like most other message pushing services, you cannot force people to join your channel, they have to subscribe to it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Typically a User chooses to *subscribe* to your channel, you cannot *"ADD"* someone to a channel.

But you may add users to groups.

Comment: Isn't any way to do that?